# iOS: Draw text on UIView with LineWidth 1px

Tags: ios, drawrect, core-text, uibezierpath, drawtext

I have a scenario where I will have to draw a text on a UIView. For which my code is

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)iRect {
    [super drawRect:iRect];
    CGContextRef aContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(aContext, [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);
    [@"s" drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, iRect.size.width, iRect.size.height) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:500] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
  }
```

With this code I can achieve:

[image]

However, since I'm using a FontSize of 500, the text lineWidth is big.
I would like to reduce the lineWidth to 1px.

Please advice on how to achieve this.

- Is there another method apart from the conventional `drawInRect`.
- Will CoreText help me get the solution

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Using UIBezierPath for the Glyph, I was able to get the Path of the Character. But the path that is achieved is through the border of the character. hence, I get the text as:

[image]

***Can this be made a single line ?***

Answer (score 2):

Even though it looks as if the letter S is drawn as a line of a certain width, that's not the case. If you look closer, then you'll see that the line width varies. It's in fact a complex graphical construct defined by it's outline. It's even more obvious if you use a font with serifs. As a consequence, there is no such thing as a text line width.

The best solution probably is to use a different font that has the look as if it was drawn using a narrow pen. I'm not sure if such a font is preinstalled on iOS.

Comment: True.. I dont think I can find a Font which will solve the problem. I hope CoreText and CGGlyph can give me a solution.

Comment: I don't think CoreText or CGGlyph will help because letters (or glyphs) are shapes (and not paths where you could apply a line width).